# kineticjs: Can I set the Drag and Drop Bounds as a circle track?

Tags: kineticjs

I saw the sample of drag and bound is like:

```
// set drag bounds after instantiation
shape.setDragBounds({
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  right: 200,
  bottom: 200
});
```

but would it be possible to set it as a circle track? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/jjR55/3/

Comment: Please check this out. Its from [html5canvastutorial.com](http://www.html5canvastutorial.com) http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-bounds-tutorial-with-kineticjs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, doable like so:

```
dragBoundFunc: function(pos) {
        var x = 100;  // your center point
        var y = 100;  // your center point 
        var radius = 50;
        var scale = radius / Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pos.x - x, 2) + Math.pow(pos.y - y, 2)); // distance formula ratio
        if(scale < 1)
          return {
            y: Math.round((pos.y - y) * scale + y),
            x: Math.round((pos.x - x) * scale + x)
          };
        else
          return pos;
      }
```